# Chef start handlers

Tags: logging, chef-infra

I am reading the `client.log` file and outputting any errors to another txt file on the client. Then I am checking to see if that file contains anything, and if so I create a bug. This functionality works perfectly fine. My issue is I have to have my recipe run as the last recipe in the chef run. This is a problem, because if an error does occur, then my recipe doesn't get run, because not all errors are caught in an exception. I am now trying to run my recipes in a start handler, that way it will catch the errors from the previous run, which is fine. But I cannot get the start handler to work properly.

I was following an example in a chef book. When I restart the chef-client service I get the error "Windows could not start the Chef Client Service service on Local Computer. Error 1053 the service did not respond to the start or the control request in a timely fashion."

Here is my handler code

```
reqire "chef/handler"
class Chef
  class Handler
    class AwesomeStartHandler < Chef::Handler
      def report
        chef::Log.info("Handler executed")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And this is what I was told to put at the top of the client.rb file.

```
verify_api_cert true
require "path/awesome_start_handler.rb"
example_start_handler = Chef::Handler::AwesomeStartHandler.new
start_handlers << example_start_handler
```

The below code works in client.rb, but as soon as I uncomment the require, I get the same error message. the exception_handlers does create a failed-run-data.json, and it does contain the errors, but since the code I had already written will work with a start handler, it is preferred if I got that to work.

```
#require 'path/awesome_start_handler.rb'
#start_handlers << Chef::Handler::AwesomeStartHandler.new()
require 'chef/handler/error_report'
report_handlers << Chef::Handler::ErrorReport.new()
exception_handlers << Chef::Handler::ErrorReport.new()
```

Comment: Why not using an error handler if you aim to catch errors only ? It will only be trigered at end of chef run if there was an error (exception raised), from Chef 11.0 (IIRC) the report and error handlers are always run as chef fork to converge and the handlers are managed by the parent process.

Comment: I was not sure if an exception was always thrown when I received a ERROR or FATAL in the log, but I was informed that an exception is always thrown, but not always caught. so What are saying may work. Where exactly do I place my code, that is another problem I am having I have the cookbooks chef_client and chef-handler.

Comment: I'm on phone and links copy us quite hard, I'll do a more complete answer tomorrow, for Error level, a report handler is the way to go, it will be able to handle the resources failing, even if ignore_failure is true.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the help. With what I have been reading online, If I don't go the client.rb route that was in the Chef book I was using, I will have to include the recipe I put the handler in at the beginning of the chef run. Due to the way Chef runs at my company, I am not allowed to put anything at the start of the run, only at the end.

Comment: A report/error handler will run at end regardless of when it has been loaded so it should not be a problem at all. A start handler need to be loaded at start, but report should not as it parse the run state at the very end.

Answer (score 0):

Worth an answer even if it won't be really long:

According to [this part of chef documentation](https://docs.chef.io/handlers.html#custom-handlers) a report handler could be loaded at any time, it is often loaded at the beginning but that's not mandatory.

A Report handler will be able to parse the run_status property for updated/failing resources which does not stop chef (no exception raised), an error handler will be called when an exception is raised.

You can write a custom handler which handle both, it will have to define what to do in its `report` method depending on the `run_status.failed?` return value.

Documentation linked above has a lot of exemple from existing handlers wich are a good starting point to write your own.

---

Precision after comments and question edit:

The way you're describing is the historical way to load report handlers from `client.rb` file.

The start handler is a particular one and has its own setting in `client.rb` named `start_handler`. See [there](https://docs.chef.io/handlers.html#start-handlers) for the official documentation about how to configure a start handler. According to one of your comment, the attributes to drive the chef_client cookbook sounds the best bet.

Comment: Although I will probably end up using the error handler in the end, I would like to get the start handler to work if anyone could help, because I already have code written and working that grabs the errors that occurred in the last chef run, and work is done based on what the errors are, like determining if it has already been reported. So In the interest of time, the start handler is what would allow me to continue on with my original plans. I will update the question with a little more of what I discovered yesterday.

Comment: If you really want to use a start handler, it can't be loaded from a recipe, it has to be loaded in the `client.rb` as it must start before anything else in the run start (including syncing cookbooks as this could take some time and part of the handler would be to report the progress for exemple).

Comment: And that is how the book "Customizing Chef"  by O'reilly says to do it, but I didn't have any luck getting it to work that way. the first two code pieces in my question is how the book says to do it, and the last code piece is what I am currently using, since I got rid of the error, and saw some outcome. For some reason the require for the ruby file that has the handler in it isn't working, so I'm starting with trying to get that to work.

Comment: I'm affraid this book covers only report handlers, as what you describe is the original way to include handlers (from chef 10). I've updated my answer to point to the correct source I hope.

Comment: Is the chef-client cookbook included somewhere already, so that the default recipe runs? If so, the code to install and configure gems needs to go in a recipe in that cookbook, and must be included in the default recipe? This looks like it installs the gems, and enables the the start handler. How/Where do I actually say what I want the start handler to do?

Comment: The what is in the handler itself, for the rest you should read the README of the chef_client cookbook [here](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/chef-client#start-report-exception-handlers)

Comment: I just found out we do not create the client.rb content through the chef-client cookbook's config.rb. We use a script, so I'm setting this aside for now.

Comment: @balex ok, I though you were using per your comment under the question saying "I have the cookbooks chef_client and chef-handler. " but well, if using the cookbook config recipe not an option, I can't help anymore

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I was under the impression those cookbooks were what we were using, until I checked with a coworker and the said we do not. It only seemed logical that those cookbooks would have been used, but I guess not.